# Ruby on Rails ajax error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

i am trying to submit form using rails remote form method it invoke correctly data send to database correctly and stored but when i am trying to get the response in html it showing reference error in Jquery

Rails Form:

```
        <%= form_for(@comment,remote: true) do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :song_id, value: @song.id %>
          <%= f.text_area :comment, class: "form-control col-8", placeholder: "comment", id: "comment", :required => true %>
          <%= f.submit "post", id: "comment_post", class: "btn btn-primary col-4" %>
        <% end %>
```

Controller for this:

```
def create
    params[:comment][:user_id] = current_user.id
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
       render inline: '<li><%= @comment.comment %></li>'.html_safe
    else
       render inline: 'Sorry Something wrong try again pls :)'.html_safe
    end
end
```

Coffee Script

```
   $(document).ready ->
      $("#new_comment").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
      console.log data
      $('#comment_display').append xhr.responseText
      $('#comment').val(" ")
      $('#comment_count').html(parseInt($('#comment_count').text())+1)
    ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
      console.log error
      $("#comment_display").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

it prints ajax:error part

What wrong i am doing in this ? 
please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing 'inline' with 'text'

```
       render text: '<li><%= @comment.comment %></li>'.html_safe
```

Comment: It is printing as it is not the value of @comment.comment